# How do I call an external app in zabbix 2.2?

Tags: linux, zabbix, zabbix-agent

I have an app that reports the status of another app.  It does a little more than just check if the app is in the process list.

It returns 0 if OK and -1 if error.

How would I call this app through the zabbix agent and use that to determine if the process that it checks on is OK or not?

Comment: https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/2.2/manual/config/items/userparameters/extending_agent

Comment: Thanks for the link @MichaelHampton.  What's completely unclear is how the output from scripts/commands are interpreted by zabbix.  Using zabbix_get it works.  When I create a template and link it to a host I get "unsupported" as my error.  The key is correct though.  Any ideas?

Comment: Never mind, I fixed it.  Turns out I was monitoring on localhost instead of the DNS name. So of course it wasn't supported.  Thanks for your help.  You could pull out the relevant bits from the docs and paste them here and I'd be happy accept an answer.

Comment: @Matt - you should post that as an answer isntead of as a comment, as it's not obvious that you've been able to resolve the issue (hence why you just got a new answer)

Answer (score 1):

There is a option in `zabbix-agent` named **UserParameter** which can help you. In this case you yourself generate a parameter on the guest machine and on the zabbix server you just define an item with the key you specified on that machine. See this links:

[User parameters](https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/2.2/manual/config/items/userparameters)